# Show that $\{\lvert{c_k}\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$ spans $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

In trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $\{\lvert{a_i}\rangle\}_{i=1}^{M}$ be a basis of $U$ and $\{\lvert{b_j}\rangle\}_{j=1}^{N}$ be a basis of $V$. The set of vectors $\{\lvert{c_k}\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$ defined by
>   $$\lvert{c_k}\rangle = \begin{cases} (\lvert{a_k}\rangle, \lvert{0}\rangle_v) & \mbox{if } 1 \leq k \leq M \\ (\lvert{0}\rangle_u, \lvert{b_{k-M}}\rangle) &\mbox{if }M+1 \leq k \leq M+N \end{cases}$$
>   form a basis for the direct sum $W = U \oplus V$.

I have to prove that $\{\lvert{c_k}\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$ spans $W$.

I understand that the proof of the theorem also requires proving that $\{\lvert{c_k}\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$ is linearly independent, but I understand how to go about doing that. What I'm having trouble with is proving the first condition that $\{\lvert{c_k}\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$ spans $W$.

I'm only new to vector spaces, so I don't fully yet understand the concept of span, much less how to go about proving it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this: $(\lvert{a_k}\rangle, \lvert{0}\rangle_v)$?

Comment: The ordered pair consisting of the vector $\lvert{a_k}\rangle$ and the zero vector in $V$

Answer (score 0):

Let $|u\rangle\in\mathcal{U},|v\rangle\in\mathcal{V},|w\rangle\in\mathcal{W}$. We want to show that $\forall|w\rangle\in\mathcal{W},\ \exists\ \gamma_1,\gamma_2,...,\gamma_{M+N}\in\mathbb{C} \ s.t. |w\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^{M+N}\gamma_k|c_k\rangle$.
So we note that:
$$|w\rangle=(|u\rangle,|v\rangle)=(\sum_{i=1}^M\alpha_i|a_i\rangle,\sum_{j=1}^N\beta_j|b_j\rangle)$$
The two components are valid representations of $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$ since they are linear combinations of their respective basis vectors. Thus for any $|w\rangle$ we can select $\gamma_k=\alpha_k$ for $1\leq k\leq M$ and $\gamma_k=\beta_k$ for $M+1\leq k\leq M+N$. This means every vector $|w\rangle\in\mathcal{W}$ can be represented by a linear combination of the vectors in $\{|c_k\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$, or in other words,
$$\mathcal{W}=Span\{|c_k\rangle\}_{k=1}^{M+N}$$